# Matlab for loop trouble

Tags: matlab, for-loop, double

I'm trying to understand for loops better in Matlab since for some reason they don't work like other languages.

```
values = zeros(1,7);
for i =[1, 4, 10, 15, 22, 24, 36]
        variable = function(input, input, i);
        values(i) = function(input, variable);
end
```

So values becomes a 1x36 double where for i I get results, but any number that isn't i gets a column set to 0. Why does it still add columns for values I didn't choose for i?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are preallocating `values` with `7` entries. When you assign a value at entry `10`, entries `8` and `9` must be created too, and Matlab fills them with `0`.

Here's an example:

```
>> clear
>> values = ones(1,7) % preallocate with ones
values =
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
>> values(4) = 40
values =
     1     1     1    40     1     1     1
>> values(10) = 100 % the array will have to grow
values =
     1     1     1    40     1     1     1    0     0   100
```

Note also that having an array growing is not desirable, as it negatively impacts speed. It's better to [preallocate](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) to the final size, whenever it is known in advance.

---

*Thanks to [@Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5358968/steve) for the edit*

If you want the results to be stored in consecutive entries, consider using a counting variable, e.g. `k` for your indexing which increases by `1` each step of the loop.

```
values = zeros(1,7);
% k stores the number of steps of the loop
k = 0;
for i =[1, 4, 10, 15, 22, 24, 36]
        % increment k
        k = k+1;
        variable = function(input, input, i);
        values(k) = function(input, variable);
end
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. But then how would I get around this? Deleting all those columns manually looks very messy...

Comment: @BlackDrMario Maybe you don't want to store each value at entry `i`,  but at entry `k` where `k` is a counter that increases one by one in each iteration